# PHP Regular Expression for the field

Tags: regex, preg-match

I'm finding the PHP Regular Expression for preg_match. Below are the conditions for the field named "city".

- not allow all special character
- not allow all numbers
- one of these:

  - allow alphabets with spaces
  - allow alphabets with special character with spaces
  - allow alphabets with numbers with spaces

allowed pattern

- test
- test test
- test 123 test
- test &## fine

not allowed pattern

- `423`
- `423 646 215`
- `$%^&`
- `%%%^^  ^(^%$`

Comment: Post some sample text and the correct matches.

Comment: please check question. I've added more explanation there.

Comment: I've tried this For alphabets #[^a-z0-9]#i and for numbers /^[0-9 ]+$/ separately with two condition

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use

```
^(?!^[\W\d]*$).*$
```

which remove all the input that doesn't contain char in the range a-z

Comment: I'm newbies on stackoverflow so unable to vote this answer.

Comment: @Morphew you can mark it as accepted anyway using the tick (V shaped) near the vote button, it will give you two rep points